# How to create a website or pop up that will hang the browser

Tags: browser, popup, freeze

i'm working on building a website pop up that hangs the browser and when the pop up runs user can not close the browser  by any means (ex-by clicking on closing window or closing the tab) i'm at a dead end any leads

Answer (score 1):

This likely isn't possible, and if it is possible the browser developers would likely consider it a bug and fix the code so the browser wouldn't hang. Also, the only uses I can think of for this are malicious.